# Obtain a subset of 2-D indices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2-D data containing bad values (0 indicates bad). My goal is to replace each bad value with its nearest neighbor that isn't bad.

SciPy's `NearestNDInterpolator` seems like a nice way to do this. In the 2-D case, it accepts a (number of points) x 2 array of indices and a (number of points) x 1 array of corresponding values to interpolate from.

So, I need to get a subset of the indices and values: those that are "good." The code below achieves this, but `coordinates = array(list(ndindex(n_y, n_x)))` and `where(values != 0)[0]` are both messy. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
# n_y and n_x are the number of points along each dimension.

coordinates = array(list(ndindex(n_y, n_x)))

values = data.flatten()
nonzero_ind = where(values != 0)[0]

nonzero_coordinates = coordinates[nonzero_ind, :]
nonzero_values = values[nonzero_ind]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nonzero_coordinates = np.argwhere(data != 0)
nonzero_values = np.extract(data, data)
```

or simply:

```
nonzero_values = data[data!=0]
```

I initially rather missed the obvious `nonzero_values` method, but thanks to @askewchan in the comments for that.

Comment: fyi, for a boolean test, `np.extract(test, data)` is the same as `data[test]`. However, you have a good example of where `extract` is useful though you haven't taken advantage of it, since your test is `data !=0`.  Try just: `np.extract(data, data)`

Comment: You should consider creating the mask once and saving it.

Comment: @askewchan haha good point. It's easy to get lost in novel techniques and miss the obvious ones! I've edited the answer to reflect my cockup.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I need to get a subset of the indices and values: those that are "good."

If you've created a "mask" of the bad indices, you can take the negation of that mask `~` and then find the indices from the mask using `np.where`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

# Sample array
Z = np.random.random(size=(5,5))

# Use whatever criteria you have to mark the bad indices
bad_mask  = Z<.2

good_mask = ~bad_mask
good_idx  = np.where(good_mask)

print good_mask
print good_idx
```

Gives, as an example:

```
[[ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True False False  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this problem altogether is to just run your array through an image filter that would automatically 'close' those holes.  There is such a filter in `scipy.ndimage` called [`grey_closing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_closing.html):

```py
>>> from scipy import ndimage

>>> a = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
>>> a[2,2] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12,  0, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

>>> a = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)

>>> ndimage.grey_closing(a, size=2)
array([[ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [12, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [17, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [22, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

But this has unfortunate edge affects (which you can change a bit with the `mode` paramenter).  To avoid this, you could just take the new values from where the original array was 0 and place them into the original array:

```py
>>> np.where(a, a, ndimage.grey_closing(a, size=2))
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 12, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Alternatively, you could use [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/):

```py
>>> from skimage.morphology import closing, square
>>> a = np.arange(1,10, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(3,3)
>>> a[1,1] = 0

>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8)

>>> closing(a, square(2))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8)

>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8)
```

Give it `a` as the output array and the closing is done in-place:

```py
>>> closing(a, square(2), a)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8)
```

Use a larger `square` (or any shape from skimage.morphology) if you have big gaps of zeros.  The disadvantage of this (aside from the dependency) is that it seems to only work for `uint8`.